# how to add date like input type date to td table inside a JS function?

Tags: javascript

for this example

```js
  $("#add").click(function () {
      var html = "<tr>";
      html += '<td contenteditable id="data1"></td>';
      html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>';
      html += '<td contenteditable id="data3"></td>';
      html += '<td contenteditable id="data4"></td>';
      html += '<td contenteditable id="data5"></td>';
      html += '<td contenteditable id="data6"></td>';
      html += '<td contenteditable id="data7"></td>';
      html += '<td contenteditable id="data8"></td>';
      html += '<td contenteditable id="data9"></td>';
      html +=
        '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Insert</button></td>';
      html += "</tr>";
      $("#user_data tbody").prepend(html);
    });
```

if you could help me in this regard it will be appreciate it

Comment: Should there be an input field in each `td` element?

Comment: btw i have tried          html += '<td><input type="date" id="data9"></td>';

Comment: @Titulum i did that it not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why doesn't the following work for you?

```js
const tableBody = document.getElementById("table-body");

const amountOfInputs = 3;

function generateRow() {
  let generatedHtmlBody = "<tr>";
  for (let i = 1; i <= amountOfInputs; i++) {
    generatedHtmlBody += `<td><input id="input-${i}" type="date" /></td>`
  }
  generatedHtmlBody += `<td><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td></tr>`;
  return generatedHtmlBody;
}

function addRow() {
  tableBody.innerHTML += generateRow();
}

addRow();
```

```html
<button onclick="addRow()">Add row</button>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr id="table-header-first-row">
      <th>Table</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table-body">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: as i said inside a function not inside html body

Comment: But this is not inside html body? This is a javascript function that is inserting this into the HTML body. Is that not what you are asking?

Comment: Titulum sir I'll share whole code now to give you an idea

Comment: Titulum i cant post it here can i email it to you ?

Comment: @AliZadeh just edit your post and include a link to the code, that would be easier.

Comment: did you check it up?

Comment: I have, and I added a date input in your table: https://jsfiddle.net/7fkLwsga/, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: just something else please how to apply it to existing data

Comment: To apply it to existing data you should open a new question, the scope of each question on this website should be small. If I helped you, could you accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of my answer?

Comment: your code doing it for insert but not for existing data which they also in the same column

Comment: You can fill in the existing data into the `input` field using the `value` attribute: `<input type="date" value="2020-02-14">`. This will set a default value.

Comment: it only doing for my insert when i add new row

Comment: which is awosome but i need it for whole column

Comment: value  just change the insert row not all the column

Comment: @AliZadeh, please create a new question for that specific issue.

Comment: i will post new question for that but btw my insert dosent work now

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, you can make it like that.

```
$("#add").click(function () {
    var html = `
   <td contenteditable id="data1">
    <input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2018-07-22" min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31">
   </td>
   <td contenteditable id="data2"></td>
   <td contenteditable id="data3"></td>
   <td contenteditable id="data4"></td>
   <td contenteditable id="data5"></td>
   <td contenteditable id="data6"></td>
   <td contenteditable id="data7"></td>
   <td contenteditable id="data8"></td>
   <td contenteditable id="data9"></td>
   <td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Insert</button></td>
   </tr>
   `;
    $("#user_data tbody").prepend(html);
  });
```

You can write inside **``** as you write in **HTML**

Comment: doesn't bring any calendar like it do in html input type date